# Silverlight application converted to window application doesn't work

Tags: winforms, silverlight, realsense

Below link is an Intel realsense application using Silverlight. I have tried this
in window form and it doesn't work.

http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2015/04/27/intel-realsense-camera-f200-segmenting-video-for-green-screen-scenarios.aspx

For mediaelement I used window media player and for image I used picturebox. Video is working in this but no image in picture.

Can anyone tell how to make this same application works in window application as I'm new to this.

Comment: can you share  your piece of code for non-working picturebox

Comment: The code is given in the provided link above. Just want to convert to window application

Comment: i want to see what you tried , so it would be easier to correct it from there